# Viber No Video No Call [22.04]

Tags: deb, viber

I cannot make either voice call  or video call.
When I go to settings and see if the call settings are okay, but the video doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: have you found any solution yet?

Comment: sorry no solution yet

Answer (score 0):

"Download Viber for Windows 8 and lower" from [www.viber.com/en/download/](http://www.viber.com/en/download/)
then install ViberSetup.exe file in wine-7.0 with settings for Windows 8 version.

Running Viber in Wine presents some difficulties such as displaying emoticons and launching links from a chat. There is also no ringing sound when a call comes in. All these problems are solved by installing Viber v. 18.2.0.2 via Flatpak.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy for the concern.